# notepad++ add to end line

Tags: arrays, notepad++

I've got a txt file with list of names.

```
Tim
John
Steve
Melanie
```

I want to the list turned into:

```
Tim:"",
John:"",
Steve:"",
Melanie:""
```

How can I add/append the `:"",` to the end of these names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple.
Don't use the notepad++ regex mode, rather use the extended mode.

In the find what field, put `\r` and in the replace with field put `:"",` or your desired keys.

[image]